# error updating my database vb 2008

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-update, error-code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmChangePassword
    Public dbrs As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public Provider As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Public dbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Private Sub frmChangePassword_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnChangePassword_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChangePassword.Click

        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = login.mdb"), _
         cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE LogInAdmin SET Password= ? WHERE Username= ? ;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtNewPassword.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtUsername.Text)
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Changed")
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: please add more detail about your problem just sharing code would not help

Answer (score 1):

The word PASSWORD is a reserved keyword for MS-Access/JET, you need to use square brackets around it

```
cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE LogInAdmin SET [Password]= ? WHERE Username= ? ;", cn)
```

However, it is a bad idea to use these [reserved keywords](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266), if it is still possible I suggest to change that field name and learn how to store an [hash of the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database) instead of clear text.